# How to align arguments in a function?

Tags: equations, align, matrices

I've been (unsuccessfully) trying to re-write the below image in Tex and encountered several problems :

- how to  align the `\varphi` functions
- how to draw the vertical bars

This is what I am trying to achieve : [image]

And this is what I have :

[image]

And here is my code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
% Language setting
% Replace `english' with e.g. `spanish' to change the document language
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Nat}{Nat}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}


\begin{matrix}

    G(f,\gamma): & \Nat (\Hom_A,F)  & \longrightarrow & \Nat(\Hom_A,F')
    
    \\
    
       & \varphi        & \longmapsto     & 
       
\begin{matrix}
    \varphi': & \mathbb{\Hom_B} & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{F'}
    
    \\
    
       & 
\begin{matrix}
    \bigg|^{\varphi_X': & \mathbb{(\Hom_B,\times)} & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{F'(x)}     \\
       & h         & \longmapsto     & (\gamma \circ \varphi) \times (h \circ f)}}
\end{matrix}
    
\end{matrix}
\end{matrix}


\end{document}
```

By aligning `\varphi'`and `\varphi'_X` I mean make it look like this :

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the idea, fix the symbols. But, please, apply `\mathbb` to a single uppercase letter; `\mathbb{\Hom_B}` is wrong as is `\mathbb{F'}`. If you want the letters to be in blackboard bold, use

```
\Hom_{\mathbb{B}}
\mathbb{F}'
```

Here's the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Nat}{Nat}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{l@{\;}c>{{}}c<{{}}l}
G(f,\gamma)\colon & \Nat (\Hom_A,F)  & \longrightarrow & \Nat(\Hom_A,F') \\
    
                  & \varphi          & \longmapsto     & 
  \begin{array}[t]{|@{\;}l@{\;}l}
    \varphi'\colon & \Hom_B \longrightarrow F' \\
    & \varphi_X'\colon \begin{array}[t]{|@{\;}c>{{}}c<{{}}l}
                       \Hom(B,x) & \longrightarrow & F'(x) \\
                       h         & \longmapsto     & (\gamma\circ\varphi)\times(h \circ f)
                       \end{array}
  \end{array}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Setting `\arraycolsep` to zero allows to manually add the right spacing.

[image]

The `[t]` option means that the `array` is vertically aligned at the top line; with `@{\;}` we specify a space like for relations; with `>{{}}c<{{}}` we specify a centered column reserved for relations (the arrows here), so the net effect would be `{}\longrightarrow{}` and TeX will add the spaces around the relation by itself.

An alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Nat}{Nat}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{l@{\;}c>{{}}c<{{}}l}
G(f,\gamma)\colon & \Nat (\Hom_A,F)  & \longrightarrow & \Nat(\Hom_A,F') \\
    
                  & \varphi          & \longmapsto     & 
  \begin{array}[t]{|@{\;}l@{\;}l}
    \varphi'\colon   & \Hom_B \longrightarrow F' \\
    \varphi_X'\colon & \begin{array}[t]{|@{\;}c>{{}}c<{{}}l}
                       \Hom(B,x) & \longrightarrow & F'(x) \\
                       h         & \longmapsto     & (\gamma\circ\varphi)\times(h \circ f)
                       \end{array}
  \end{array}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With braces: top alignment requires `delarray`, center alignment doesn't (and is clearly preferable).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,delarray}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Nat}{Nat}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{l@{\;}c>{{}}c<{{}}l}
G(f,\gamma)\colon & \Nat (\Hom_A,F)  & \longrightarrow & \Nat(\Hom_A,F') \\
    
                  & \varphi          & \longmapsto     & 
  \begin{array}[t]\{{@{\;}l@{\;}l}.
    \varphi'\colon   & \Hom_B \longrightarrow F' \\
    \varphi_X'\colon & \begin{array}[t]\{{@{\;}c>{{}}c<{{}}l}.
                       \Hom(B,x) & \longrightarrow & F'(x) \\
                       h         & \longmapsto     & (\gamma\circ\varphi)\times(h \circ f)
                       \end{array}
  \end{array}
\end{array}
\]

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{l@{\;}c>{{}}c<{{}}l}
G(f,\gamma)\colon & \Nat (\Hom_A,F)  & \longrightarrow & \Nat(\Hom_A,F') \\
    
                  & \varphi          & \longmapsto     & 
   \left\{\begin{array}{@{\;}l@{\;}l}
    \varphi'\colon   & \Hom_B \longrightarrow F' \\
    \varphi_X'\colon & \left\{\begin{array}{@{\;}c>{{}}c<{{}}l}
                       \Hom(B,x) & \longrightarrow & F'(x) \\
                       h         & \longmapsto     & (\gamma\circ\varphi)\times(h \circ f)
                       \end{array}\right.
  \end{array}\right.
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for answer ! Just a clarification , what does all these long arguments in `\begin{array}{l@{\;}c>{{}}c<{{}}l}` and `\begin{array}[t]{|@{\;}c>{{}}c<{{}}l}` mean ?

Comment: And also, is it possible to align the `\varphi` column with the `\varphi_X`one ?

Comment: @Gigi I’ll add some descriptions, but I’m not sure what alignment you’re talking about.

Comment: I have edited the question so you can now see what do I mean by "aligning `\varphi`and `\varphi_X`.

Comment: @Gigi I added a possible alignment, fix it to suit your taste. I'd not use the vertical rules, to be honest.

Comment: Thank you very much @egreg! Last question (promise), in order to use brackets instead of the vertical rules, can I simply replace the vertical line in `\begin{array}[t]{|@{\;}c>{{}}c<{{}}l}` by `\{` ?

Comment: @Gigi No. You need `delarray` for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138266/discussion-between-gigi-and-egreg).

Comment: @Gigi I added the version with the braces. Please, no more.